# How to use non-english characters? Android, onSearchRequested()

Tags: android, search, non-english

`onSearchRequested()` function only accept English character. For example when I put **ş** character in search box, it doesn't show me anything.

How can I define non-english characters into `onSearchRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern and matcher .. it would b better

see this As You Can Change pattern according to you ... by using symbols like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
 try this

```
EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);


                Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
                Matcher ms = ps.matcher(state.getText().toString());
                boolean bs = ms.matches();
                if (bs == false) {
                    if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "state,";

                    else
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid state,";

                }
```

Comment: I want to use onSearchRequest(), because it recommend results. How can I define non-english characters to onSearchRequest?